# Equivalent of imu_transformer for ROS2?

Tags: ros2

I'm converting a ROS1 project to ROS2. One of its dependencies is the [imu_transformer](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_transformer) package, which is supported in ROS1 all the way to Noetic, but has not been ported to ROS2 as of Iron.

Is there a reason for that? Has TF2 been updated to include proper IMU message transformation between reference frames? Or is it just that the `imu_transformer` package hasn't been ported over yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a community port that has been merged into the "ros2" branch of the main repository for this project - https://github.com/ros-perception/imu_pipeline/pull/17. That pull request also includes some details of how the ROS 2 version is different from what was in ROS 1 (mainly dropping older message type support)

However, it hasn't been released as Debians so you'll have to build from source.